# Basic threading with one background worker and other thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm very much a beginner in both python and programming. Trying to get multithreading work but haven't managed so far. Grateful for any help or tips.

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import requests

class crawler:

    def get_urls(self):
        while True:
            #r = self.s.get('http:\\someurl')
            time.sleep(1)
            print 'Thread 1'

    def thread_test(self):
        while True:
            print 'Thread 2'
            time.sleep(1)

crawl = crawler()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=crawl.get_urls()).start()
    Thread(target=crawl.thread_test()).start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while since i have done thread programming in python but I remembered that you will have to call `.join()` on each thread or else the main thread will exit before your spawn thread get a chance to execute.

```
T1 = Thread(target=crawl.get_urls()).start()
T2 = Thread(target=crawl.thread_test()).start()
T1.join()
T2.join()
```

should do the trick

`edit` I just looked into python `threading` library the issue is that `target` is expecting a callable object. when you call `target=crawl.get_urls()` the method was being evaluated rather than passing the method.

```
from threading import Thread
```

import time
import requests

class crawler:

```
def get_urls(self):
    while True:
        #r = self.s.get('http:\\someurl')
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'Thread 1'

def thread_test(self):
    while True:
        print 'Thread 2'
        time.sleep(1)

crawl = crawler()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=crawl.get_urls).start()
    Thread(target=crawl.thread_test).start()
```

ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

Comment: This still does not work. I only get the output from thread 1.

Comment: It has been a while since I did this, but I have been able to fix your code. the method `get_urls` was being evaluated rather than being passed to `Thread`. I have updated up answer.

Comment: That was it! Thanks very much Abbas. This took me far too much time.